# I want to filter by id the firebase realtime-database in my asp.net web api application, but I do not know how to build up the query

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a asp.net web api project with firebase real-timedatabase. I use firebaseclient libraries. But I want to know how to develop queries using firebase client.

I have already created query get all the suppliers. It is working.

And another to get suppliers by id. It gives syntax errors. This is not working.

```
//method to get all suppliers. Working properly
[Route("getAll")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetSuppliers()
{
    var firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient(<firebase url>);

    //Retrieve data from Firebase
    var suppliers = await firebaseClient
    .Child("suppliers")
    .OnceAsync<SupplierModel>();

     List<SupplierModel> supplierList = new List<SupplierModel>();

     foreach (var sup in suppliers)
     {
         supplierList.Add(sup.Object);
     }
     HttpResponseMessage response;
     response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, supplierList);
     return response;
}

//method to filter by id. Have syntax errors

[Route("addSuppllier/{supplierId}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetSupplierById([FromUri] string supplierId)
{
    var firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient(<firebase url>);

    //Retrieve data from Firebase
    var suppliers = await firebaseClient
    .Child("suppliers")
    .OrderBy("supplierId")
    .EqualTo(supplierId);
    List<SupplierModel> supplierList = new List<SupplierModel>();
    foreach (var sup in suppliers)
    {
        supplierList.Add(sup.Object);
    }
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, supplierList);
    return response;
}
```

First query retrieves all suppliers properly.
Second query has syntax errors.

Comment: Could you try swapping out `.OrderBy("supplierId");` with `.OrderByChild("supplierId");` and see if that works? You are specifying that "Suppliers" is the Child, just a thought.

Comment: my collection name is suppliers and there is field named, supplierId. So I want filter by that column. 
And also there is no function called orderByChild.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this approach.

```
FirebaseResponse response = await firebaseClient.GetAsync("suppliers");
JObject jsonResponse = response.ResultAs<JObject>();

var query = new List<SupplierModel>();
if (jsonResponse != null)
{
foreach (var item in jsonResponse)
        {
         var value = item.Value.ToString();
         var supplierModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SupplierModel>(value);

         //note: supplier model should have id attribute
         supplierModel.Id = item.Key;
         query.Add(supplierModel);
        };
 }
```

Then filter the **query** by **Id** if it is not null.

Comment: and if you have a thousand data in that "suppliers" ?